# Live data observer stop when push new activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, observers

I have two Activities, each one have its `ViewModel`, and I need to make the first `Activity` live data observer keep running when push to the new `Activity`, the current happening is when launch second `Activity` the observer stop working.

```
private fun observer() {
    viewModel.myData.observe(this, {
        when (it) {
            it -> {
                it.let {
                    val intent = Intent(Events.DATA_EVENT.value)
                    intent.putExtra("data", it)
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)

                }
            }

        }
    })
}
```

How can I always observe the new data in first `Activity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`observeForever(Observer)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#observeforever) method. An observer added via `observeForever(Observer)` is considered as always active and thus will be always notified about modifications. For those observers, you should manually call [`removeObserver(Observer)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#removeobserver). In `Activity`:

```
val observer = Observer<String> { // use your data class instead of String generic type
    // ...
}

// in onCreate() method
viewModel.myData.observeForever(observer)

// in onDestroy() method
viewModel.myData.removeObserver(observer)
```

Comment: it's worked thank you

Comment: Thanks Man, this is what i was looking for